# Can we find Gaussian primes $\pi = 1 + 8 \mathbb{Z}[i]$ with $N(\pi) < 1000$?

Tags: prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, sagemath

It's an exercise in computational number theory.  Either by hand or by computer, can we find the Gaussian primes $\pi = 1 + 8 \mathbb{Z}[i]$?  To keep the list finite I guess we could have $N(\pi) < 1000$.

For example, is $\mathfrak{p} = (1+8i)$ a prime?  Or $\mathfrak{p} = (-7 + 8i)$? I don't even know how to index the primes less than these.  The norms are $1^2 + 8^2 = 65 = 5 \times 13$ and $(-7)^2 + 8^2 = 113$, so the first could factor and the second does not.

For $\mathfrak{p} = (a + bi)$ to check it is prime over $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, is it sufficient to check that $N(\mathfrak{p}) = a^2 + b^2$ is a prime over $\mathbb{Z}$?

It would be great to see the code in `Sage` or `Pari/GP` and that would be an acceptable answer.

Comment: Pari/GP:  for(a=1,sqrtint(1000),for(b=1,sqrtint(1000),p=64*(a^2+b^2)+16*a+1;if(isprime(p)&&p<1000,print([8*a+1+8*b*I,p]),)))

Comment: Yes, it's enough to check if the norm is a prime, for if there were nontrivial factors, their norms would be nontrivial factos of the norm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One could enumerate Gaussian integers within a range, say all $a + i b$
with $a$ and $b$ from $-30$ to $30$, and test whether they are prime and
satisfy the congruence (to be faster, enumerate only those that satisfy
the congruence, and test whether they are prime).

```
sage: G = GaussianIntegers()
sage: r = 30
sage: good = [] # prime and equal to 1 modulo (8 * ZZ[i])
sage: nope = [] # others
sage: for a in (-r .. r):
....:     for b in (-r .. r):
....:         g = G((a, b))
....:         if a % 8 ==1 and b % 8 == 0 and g.is_prime():
....:             good.append(g)
....:         else:
....:             nope.append(g)
....:
```

Then one could plot as follows:

```
sage: plot_good = point2d(good, color='red', size=10)
sage: plot_nope = point2d(nope, color='blue', size=1)
sage: (plot_good + plot_nope).show(aspect_ratio=1, figsize=7)
Launched png viewer for Graphics object consisting of 2 graphics primitives
```

[image: Gaussian primes in 1 + 8 ZZ[i]]

or save the plot as a png file as follows:

```
sage: (plot_good + plot_nope).save('gaussian_primes.png', aspect_ratio=1, figsize=7)
```

Check our list for counterexamples to "prime in the Gaussian integers implies prime norm":

```
sage: [g for g in good if not g.norm().is_prime()]
[-23, -7]
```

The prime Gaussian integers $-7$ and $-23$ lie in
$1 + 8 \mathbb{Z}[i]$, but their norms are $7^2$ and $23^2$.